# Using logical OR operator inside a loop to sort an array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array like this:

```js
var planets_info = [
    {
    "name": "Mercury",
    "size": 120,
    "color": "gray",
  },
  {
    "name": "Earth",
    "size": 100,
    "color": "blue",
  },
  {
    "name": "Mars",
    "size": 200,
    "color": "red",
  }
];
```

That I am trying to sort based on name and size or color.
This is defined like this:

```js
var sorts = "size,name"; // or size, name, color dynamic value
```

I can do sorting like this:

```js
planets_info = planets_info.sort( function(a, b){
        return a.size - b.size || a.color - b.color;
        //  or
        // return a.size - b.size || a.color - b.color || a.name - b.name;

        //  or
        // a.color - b.color || a.name - b.name;

});
```

But I dont know how to modify the sort so it sorts based on the values from `var sorts` - so  `a.size - b.size || a.color - b.color;` will be dynamic based on the values from `sorts` - it can be based on `name,size` or `name,size,color` which will be added by `||` :

```js
var sorts = "size,name";
sorts = sorts.split(',');

sorts.forEach(element=> {
    console.log("sort " + element);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

You can access keys using a variable by using the bracket notation:

```js
const obj = {
  "name": "Mercury",
  "size": 120,
  "color": "gray",
};

const key = "name";

console.log(obj[key]);
```

Furthermore, if your string is always comma separated, you can call [`String#split()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable) to convert it into keys:

```js
const sorts = "name,size,color";

const keys = sorts.split(",");

console.log(keys);

const obj = {
  "name": "Mercury",
  "size": 120,
  "color": "gray",
};

console.log(obj[keys[0]]);
console.log(obj[keys[1]]);
console.log(obj[keys[2]]);
```

Before we continue, I have to point out that subtracting two values only works if you're sorting numbers, not if you're sorting strings. For example

```js
console.log("Mars" - "Mercury");
console.log("red" - "blue");
```

If you want a more universal sorting, you can use the relation comparison operators `<` and `>` that works on numbers, strings, and some objects like dates. Keep in mind that [you **have to** return three values, not just true and false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison). So with this in mind, it's easy to create a generic comparison function:

```js
const compare = (a, b) => {
  if (a < b)
    return -1;
  
  if (a > b)
    return 1;
    
  return 0;
}
                                         // sort order:
console.log(compare("Mars", "Mercury")); // Mars, Mercury
console.log(compare("red", "blue"));     // blue, red
console.log(compare(120, 100));          // 100, 120

console.log(compare(                     // 7th of January, 11th of January
  new Date("2021-01-07"),
  new Date("2021-01-11")
));
```

Now with this, alongside [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) you can achieve dynamic sorting:

```js
const compare = (a, b) => {
  if (a < b)
    return -1;
  
  if (a > b)
    return 1;
    
  return 0;
}

function sorter(arr, sorts) {
  const keys = sorts.split(",");
  return arr.sort((a, b) => 
    keys.reduce((acc, key) => acc || compare(a[key], b[key]), 0)
  );
}

var planets_info = [
  { "name": "Mercury", "size": 120, "color": "gray", },
  { "name": "Earth"  , "size": 100, "color": "blue", },
  { "name": "Mars"   , "size": 200, "color": "red" , }
];

const result1 = sorter(
  [
    { "name": "Mercury", "size": 120, "color": "gray", },
    { "name": "Earth"  , "size": 100, "color": "blue", },
    { "name": "Mars"   , "size": 200, "color": "red" , }
  ],
  "name,size,color"
);

console.log('sorted by "name,size,color":', result1);


const result2 = sorter(
  [
    { "name": "Mercury", "size": 120, "color": "gray", },
    { "name": "Earth"  , "size": 100, "color": "blue", },
    { "name": "Mars"   , "size": 200, "color": "red" , }
  ],
  "size,name,color"
);

console.log('sorted by "name,size,color":', result2);


const result3 = sorter(
  [
    { "name": "Mercury", "size": 120, "color": "gray", },
    { "name": "Earth"  , "size": 100, "color": "blue", },
    { "name": "Mars"   , "size": 200, "color": "red" , }
  ],
  "color,name,size"
);

console.log('sorted by "name,size,color":', result3);


const result4 = sorter(
  [
    { "name": "Earth", "size": 120, "color": "blue", },
    { "name": "Earth", "size": 100, "color": "blue", },
    { "name": "Earth", "size": 200, "color": "blue" , }
  ],
  "name,color,size"
);

console.log('three Earths sorted by "name,color,size":', result4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array of the wanted keys for sorting and use a short circiut for comparison of the values.

```js
const
    planets = [{ name: "Mercury", size: 120, color: "gray" }, { name: "Earth", size: 100, color: "blue" }, { name: "Mars", size: 200, color: "red" }],
    sorts = ["size", "name"];

planets.sort((a, b) => {
    let v;
    sorts.some(k => v = a[k] > b[k] || -(a[k] < b[k]));
    return v;
});

console.log(planets);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I was going to use `localeCompare` in the return, any difference?

Comment: localeCompare will give incorrrect behaviour on numbers

Comment: will this method work with string, numbers and date?

Comment: @RainMan, if the date is in ISO format, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Note that subtracting strings doesn't work for comparisons. To properly handle numbers and strings, you'll need a more general comparison function.

```js
const planets_info = [    {    "name": "Mercury",    "size": 120,    "color": "gray",  },  {    "name": "Earth2",    "size": 100,    "color": "blue",  },  {    "name": "WEarth",    "size": 100,    "color": "blue",  },  {    "name": "Mars",    "size": 200,    "color": "red",  }];
const sorts = ['size','name'];

function sortByKeys(array,keys) {
    // works on numbers and strings
    function primitiveCompare(a,b) {
        if (a==b) return 0;
        if (a>b) return 1;
        else return -1;
    }
    array.sort((A,B)=>{
        // grab first non-zero comparison (emulates short-circuit)
        const compares = keys.map(k=>primitiveCompare(A[k],B[k]));
        return compares.filter(x=>x)[0]
    });
}

sortByKeys(planets_info,sorts);
console.log(planets_info)
```